# Sequelizejs - Searching many to many relationships

Tags: sequelize.js

If a User hasMany Projects and vice versa, I can get all of the users projects with user.getProjects() - but is there any way to search this relationship so you can page through the results and filter (say by project name) ?

Thanks.

https://gist.github.com/be3bafe8903d6b18f4ef.git

```
// connect
var Sequelize = require("sequelize")
var sequelize = new Sequelize('spike', 'anon', 'password', {
  logging: console.log
});

// models
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  status: Sequelize.TEXT
});

// associations
Project.hasMany(User, { as: 'User', as: 'contributors' });
User.hasMany(Project, { as: 'contributors' });

// execute
sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
  User.create({name: 'u1'}).then(function (user1) {
    Project.create({name: 'p1'}).then(function (project1) {
      user1.addContributor(project1).then(function () {
        user1.getContributors().then(function (projects) {
          console.log('User has '+projects.length+ ' projects');
        })
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide your model info, e.g. your `sequelize.define('User', ... )` and `sequelize.define('Project', ... )` blocks especially.

Comment: Updated with some code that creates a user, then a project, then adds the project to the user, then gets the users projects. The question is, how do I page through the users projects instead of loading the entire collection? Thanks.

Comment: Sigh, okay - paging is as easy as user1.getContributors({offset: 1, limit: 2})

Comment: Ah, and filtering is as simple as user1.getContributors({where: {name:'p1'}, offset: 1, limit: 2}) - which restricts by project name ( SELECT `Project`.* FROM (SELECT `Project`.`id`, `Project`.`name`, `Project`.`status`, `Project`.`createdAt`, `Project`.`updatedAt`, ...`ProjectsUser`.`ProjectId` AS `ProjectsUser.ProjectId` FROM `Projects` AS `Project` INNER JOIN `ProjectsUsers` AS `ProjectsUser` ON `Project`.`id` = `ProjectsUser`.`ProjectId` AND `ProjectsUser`.`UserId`=1 WHERE (`Project`.`name`='p1') LIMIT 1, 2) AS `Project`;)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple - following the same model as other queries:

```
user1.getContributors({where: {name:'p1'}, offset: 1, limit: 2}).then(function (projects) {
    console.log('User has '+projects.length+ ' projects');
})
```

This produced the following SQL which is paging the result set and filtering on PROJECT name:

```
SELECT 
    `Project` . *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `Project`.`id`,
            `Project`.`name`,
            `Project`.`status`,
            `Project`.`createdAt`,
            `Project`.`updatedAt`,
            `ProjectsUser`.`createdAt` AS `ProjectsUser.createdAt`,
            `ProjectsUser`.`updatedAt` AS `ProjectsUser.updatedAt`,
            `ProjectsUser`.`UserId` AS `ProjectsUser.UserId`,
            `ProjectsUser`.`ProjectId` AS `ProjectsUser.ProjectId`
    FROM
        `Projects` AS `Project`
    INNER JOIN `ProjectsUsers` AS `ProjectsUser` ON `Project`.`id` = `ProjectsUser`.`ProjectId`
        AND `ProjectsUser`.`UserId` = 1
    WHERE
        (`Project`.`name` = 'p1')
    LIMIT 1 , 2) AS `Project`;
```

And, you can do the same from the other side - eg query the projects that have users, filtering appropriately:

```
p2.getContributors({where: {name: 'u1'}}).then(function(users) {
  console.log('Project 1 has '+users.length+' user named u1');
});
```

Comment: See here for an expanded example: https://gist.github.com/df358a06b6a5847a33e5.git